# React typescript getting a number not found error, when adding points?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add points to an points in an object in my array. I have a league table where I declare here in App.tsx and I also add teams to the league table which seems to be fine:

```
interface Team {

  id: number;
  label:string;
  points:number;
  wins:number;
  draws:number;
  lost:number;

}
const teams: Team[] = [
  { id: 1, label: "team1", points: 0, wins: 0, draws: 0, lost: 0 },
  { id: 2, label: "team2", points: 0, wins: 0, draws: 0, lost: 0 },
  { id: 3, label: "team3", points: 0, wins: 0, draws: 0, lost: 0 },
  { id: 4, label: "team4", points: 0, wins: 0, draws: 0, lost: 0 },
];

function App() {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(teams);

  const addPointsHandler = (id: number) => {
    setPoints(
      points.map((point) => {
        //first I will get the point object
        if (point.id === id) {
          //copy everything in the point object, add a new property of points to update the object
          return {
            ...point,
            points: point.points,
            wins: point.wins,
            lost: point.lost,
            draw: point.draws,
          };
        } else {
          return point;
        }
      })
    );
  };

  const insertTeam = (team: any) => {
    setPoints((prevTeams) => {
      return [team, ...prevTeams];
    });
  };
```

In Newscore.tsx, if the number of goals team1 scores is greater than team2 then I add 3 points to the team, with wins and losses etc. My issue is that when I try to add 3 points with **team1.points** += 3, it gives an error under the word points as,' property 'points' does not exist under number', the same with wins and lost as well. Even though when I debug to return team I can see points as a property.This was working when I had it as a jsx file before

```
 const NewScore = (props:any) => {
      const [goalsTeam1, setGoalsTeam1] = useState(0);
      const [goalsTeam2, setGoalsTeam2] = useState(0);
      const [team1, setTeam1] = useState(0);
      const [team2, setTeam2] = useState(0);
    
      const submitScore = (event:any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
    
        if (Number(goalsTeam1) > Number(goalsTeam2)) {
        //getting a number not found 
        **team1.points+=3**
        team1.wins[0] += 1;
        team2.lost[0] += 1;
       
        props.addPoints();
      };
```

Comment: `team1` appears to be initialised as `0`?

Comment: What should it be initialised as instead

Comment: That's up to you, but `0` definitely doesn't have a `.points` property. I imagine it's supposed to be a team object of some sort?